# JPA as a multithread

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

ERROR [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '33' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' - 07.02.2014 11:37:20,360 request_id=9e32efa6-1374-4b1c-99e9-326a3a256b88
 Error Code:99 Error in Async Task with delay 0 :

Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Statement has already been closed
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT ID, FIRST_NAME, ISBLOCKED, LAST_NAME, MODIFIED, MSISDN, VERSION, OWNER_ID, CONTACT_ID FROM CONTACTS WHERE (OWNER_ID = ?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="VasServerfile:/data/msgadmin/wls12c/wlserver_12.1/domains/VAS-MSG-TST-DMN/servers/VAS-MSG-TST-M1-MAN1-1/tmp/_WL_user/VasServer/c7nfil/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar_VasServerPU" referenceClass=Contact sql="SELECT ID, FIRST_NAME, ISBLOCKED, LAST_NAME, MODIFIED, MSISDN, VERSION, OWNER_ID, CONTACT_ID FROM CONTACTS WHERE (OWNER_ID = ?)")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1717)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:646)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2611)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2570)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1081)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:844)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1040)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:392)

I am trying to use JPA Multithread but I took this kind of exceptions, any idea to solve the problem.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

`EntityManager` is not thread safe, so you should use an `EntityManager` instance in a single thread. In different threads you could use a `EntityManagerFactory` instance, as it is thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to isolate different HTTP threads (I mean each http thread has it's own entityManager) and you have web app you can use OpenEntityMangerInView filter.

**web.xml** fragment:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>oemInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>entityManagerFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

You can also try OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor:

http://javadox.com/org.springframework/spring-orm/3.2.6.RELEASE/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.html